# Use Multiple Display Dock with 2 laptops

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, switch, kvm-switch, multiple-computers

Scenario: USB 3.0 Docking station with multiple displays (3).

Is it possible to us a USB hub (with switched ports) and connect 2 laptops, so that depending on which one is switched on it will send signal to the Dock?

USB uplink not connected to anything
USB port 1 (turned on)  with docking station plugged into it.
USB port 2 (Laptop 1)   Switched on or off depending as I need
USB port 3 (Laptop 2)   Switched on or off depending as I need

They do make Multiple Monitor KVM, but those are way too expensive for me

Answer (score 2):

The laptops must be connected to the "uplink" USB type-B connector of the dock to function. Period.

So, your only viable solution is to purchase a USB3 switch and connect both laptops to the dock, and then just switch between them.

Here's one I found in a few moments of Google searching: [https://www.amazon.com/Plugable-Sharing-One-Button-Swapping-Computers/dp/B00JX3Q28Y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JX3Q28Y)

Comment: What did you look for, exactly? Having the same scenario as the OP, I'm looking for something just like this but for USB-C. And it's turned out to be much more difficult than expected. I have a docking station but it has only one male-out, which I'd need to split into two (one for each laptop). But perhaps that's a dumb idea and the switch you proposed is smoother.

Answer (score 0):

> Scenario: USB 3.0 Docking station with multiple displays (3).

Just so we have a frame of reference a 1080p screen resolution requires bandwidth of 1920 x 1800 x 24 bit x 60 fps = nearly 5 Gbps.  Now you want three of these on one USB connection?

USB 3.0 offers 5 Gbps.  USB 3.1 offers 10 Gbps.  USB 3.2 offers 20 Gbps but only with a USB-C connection.  USB 3.0 and USB 3.1 can offer USB and video on USB-C when coupled with DisplayPort.  I've see such KVM switches before.
https://www.startech.com/en-us/server-management/sv211hduc
This works by using the high speed data lines on USB-C.  USB over USB-A is not enough.

> Is it possible to us a USB hub (with switched ports) and connect 2 laptops, so > that depending on which one is switched on it will send signal to the Dock?

For the dock to get the data means that other computer is not just was the laptop turned off but is must also be disconnected.  There is only one hub port and for this all the data flows.  There will be sacrifice in the quality of video on each disply, either in frame rate, colors, compression, or not working at all.

One USB 3.0 cable is not enough for a single display.  What would work is 3 UBC-C running Displsyport.  Power to the monitor must come come somewhere, make it USB-C.

It sounds like you need a 2 port triple monitor KVM switch and there is no other option that can meet your needs.